# I Installed Ubuntu 22.10 on an Asus Vivobook. I found that I can connects to router but there is no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, asus, 20.10

I have done some investigation. I think I need a wifi driver which can be found here https://linux-hardware.org/?computer=f7350a87fb1f
Am I on the right track, if so, how do I download the driver ?
I Installed Ubuntu 22.10 on an Asus Vivobook.  I found that I can connects to router, it even knows the password but there is no internet. Here is some information from the laptop. ping 8.8.8.8 gives ping: connect: Network is unreachable.
Can anybody see what is going wrong and how to fix it ?

```
(router)ping 192.168.1.254
ping:connect: Network is unreachable.  
(ip) ping 95.151.90.53
ping:connect: Network is unreachable

ip route give nothing
ip neigh gives nothing
ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 84:c5:a6:77:99:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   altname wlp0s12f0

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake Host Bridge (rev 03)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 03)
00:00.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600] (rev 03)
00:0c.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 03)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 03)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 03)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SATA Controller (rev 03)
00:13.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f3)
00:13.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port (rev f3)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor I2C 4 (rev 03)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 03)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 03)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 03)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor Gaussian Mixture Model (rev 03)


nmcli

wlo1: connecting (getting IP configuration) to EE-Hub-7Pim
       "Intel Gemini Lake PCH CNVi"
       wifi (iwlwifi), 84:C5:A6:77:99:85, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlo1: disconnected
       "p2p-dev-wlo1"
       wifi-p2p, hw

lo: unmanaged
       "lo"
       loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
       
su lshw -C network

 *-network                 
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Gemini Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: c
      bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
      logical name: wlo1
      version: 03
      serial: 84:c5:a6:77:99:85
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-23-generic firmware=46.9d0122c0.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
      resources: irq:44 memory:a1114000-a1117fff
```

Comment: My bad, It's 22.10 kinetic

Comment: Please, enclose responses of network diagnostic commands: `ip addr`, `ip neigh`, `ip route`, `ping <your_router_address>`. Is  the IP address of your router LAN interface  the same as your PC default route? Try to connect your PC to router with the Ethernet cable, disable Wi-Fi, repeat the commands and show the results.

Comment: ip addr, ip neigh, ip route, ping <your_router_address>  shown at top of listing. Cant connect ethernet cable, no port on the Asus. I am doing this on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a radical solution to this problem. The 8086:31dc:8086:0264 »
/ 02-80 Intel Corporation   Gemini Lake PCH CNVi WiFi   network iwlwifi
which I need is known to have problems. So no wifi with 22.04 on an Asus Vivobook is not possible. The solution was to install 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) which allows me to use Wicd. Now I have wifi, and 18.04 is OK on the Asus which is just a video/audio machine except when on holiday.